# Move_Uploaded_File causing 500 error and won't move file

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to create a simple upload form that places the relevant details into a database. I have the database side of things working perfectly but when I try to get the file to move to the relevant target path it's failing with an Error 500.

I have checked the following:

1. Error Log, nothing wrong is displaying
2. Folder exists
3. Folder permissions are correct, it is writable

Can anyone help me resolve the issue that is causing the error?

Thank you.

EDIT: Duplicate insert and update and updated with $_FILES instead of $photos_uploaded

```
<?php
/**
 * Smarty plugin
 *
 * @package    Smarty
 * @subpackage PluginsFunction
 */

/**
 * Smarty {portfolioAdminUpload} plugin
 * Type:     function<br>
 * Name:     Display and provide function for image uploading to portfolio<br>
 * Purpose:  fetch file and move to relevant location.
 *
 * @author Kyle Holmes <kholmes at blacknovadesigns dot co dot uk>
 *
 * @param array                    $params   parameters
 * @param Smarty_Internal_Template $template template object
 *
 * @throws SmartyException
 * @return string|null if the assign parameter is passed, Smarty assigns the result to a template variable
 */
function smarty_function_portfolioAdminUpload()
{
global $db;
global $images_dir;

// initialization  
  $photo_upload_fields = '';  
  $counter = 1;  

  // If we want more fields, then use, preupload.php?number_of_fields=20  
  $number_of_fields = (isset($_GET['number_of_fields'])) ?  
    (int)($_GET['number_of_fields']) : 1;


  // Firstly Lets build the Category List  

  try {

                $stmt = $db->query('SELECT category_id,category_name FROM mod_portfolio_category') ;
                while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
                $photo_category_list .= '<option value="'.$row['category_id'].'">'.$row['category_name'].'</option>';
        }

  // Lets build the Image Uploading fields                      
                 while($counter <= $number_of_fields) { 
                        $photo_upload_fields .= '<tr><td>  
                              Photo'.$counter.'  
                              <input name="photo_filename"  
                            type="file" />  
                            </td></tr>  
                            <tr><td>  
                              Caption:  
                              <textarea name="photo_caption" cols="30"  
                                rows="1"></textarea>  
                            </td></tr>';
                                $counter++;  
                } 

            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }

  // Final Output  
  echo '<html>   

<form enctype="multipart/form-data"  
  action="" method="post"  
  name="upload_form"> 
<div class="title">Lets upload Photos</div>    
  <table width="90%" border="0"  
    align="center" style="width: 90%;">  
    <tr><td>  
      Select Category  
      <select name="category">  
      '.$photo_category_list.'  
      </select>  
    </td></tr>  
    <! - Insert the image fields here --> ' 
    .$photo_upload_fields.' 
    <tr><td>  
      <input type="submit" name="submit"  
        value="Add Photos" />  
    </td></tr>  
  </table>  
</form>  
</body>  
</html>';  

//if form has been submitted process it
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

// Fetch the image caption array 
    $photo_captions = $_POST['photo_caption'];

    $photo_category = $_POST['category'];

// Get File Type
    $file = $_FILES['photo_filename']['tmp_name'];
    $file_extension = image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($file));           


// Set Target Path for file upload 
    $target_path = '../' . $images_dir;

// Is the image really an image?
    $validextensions =  array(    
      'image/pjpeg' => 'jpg',   
      'image/jpeg' => 'jpg',   
      'image/gif' => 'gif',   
      'image/bmp' => 'bmp',   
      'image/x-png' => 'png',
      'image/png' => 'png'  
    ); 
// New Id generated             
    $new_id = $db->lastInsertId();      

// Generate a new name
    $simpleName = $_FILES["photo_filename"]['name'];   
    $filename = $new_id.rand().$_FILES["photo_filename"]['name'];

        try {

                //insert into database
                $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT mod_portfolio_photos SET photo_filename = :photoFilename, photo_caption = :photoCaption, photo_category = :photoCategory') ;
                $stmt->execute(array(
                    ':photoFilename' => $filename,
                    ':photoCaption' => $photo_captions[$counter],
                    ':photoCategory' => $photo_category,
                ));

            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }

    $target_path = $target_path . $filename;     // Set the target path with a new name of image.

    if (($_FILES["photo_filename"]["size"][$counter] < 100000000)     // Approx. 100kb files can be uploaded.
    && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {       
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo_filename"]['tmp_name'][$counter], $target_path) && is_writable($target_path)) {
// If file moved to uploads folder.
    echo '<span id="noerror">'.$simpleName.' uploaded successfully!.</span><br/><br/>';
    } 
    else {     
//  If File Was Not Moved.
    echo '<span id="error">'.$simpleName.' Failed to Upload - please try again!.</span><br/><br/>';
    }} 
    else {
//   If File Size And File Type Was Incorrect.
    echo '<span id="error">***Invalid file Size or Type***</span><br/><br/>';
    }

    $size = GetImageSize($target_path);    

// Wide Image    
    if($size[0] > $size[1])    
    {     
     $thumbnail_width = 100;     
     $thumbnail_height = (int)(100 * $size[1] / $size[0]);     
    }     

// Tall Image    
    else    
    {    
      $thumbnail_width = (int)(100 * $size[0] / $size[1]);    
      $thumbnail_height = 100;    
    }

    $gd_function_suffix = array(      
      'image/pjpeg' => 'JPEG',     
      'image/jpeg' => 'JPEG',     
      'image/gif' => 'GIF',     
      'image/bmp' => 'WBMP',     
      'image/x-png' => 'PNG'     
    );

// Get the Name Suffix on basis of the mime type     
    $function_suffix = $gd_function_suffix[$filetype];     

// Build Function name for ImageCreateFromSUFFIX     
    $function_to_read = 'ImageCreateFrom' . $function_suffix;     

// Build Function name for ImageSUFFIX     
    $function_to_write = 'Image' . $function_suffix;

// Read the source file     
    $source_handle = $function_to_read($target_path);     

    if ($source_handle) {     
// Let's create a blank image for the thumbnail     
      $destination_handle =     
        ImageCreateTrueColor($thumbnail_width, $thumbnail_height);     

// Now we resize it     
      ImageCopyResampled($destination_handle, $source_handle,     
        0, 0, 0, 0, $thumbnail_width, $thumbnail_height, $size[0], $size[1]);     
    }     

// Let's save the thumbnail     
    $function_to_write($destination_handle, '..' . $images_dir . '/tb_' . $filename);

    }
    }
```

Comment: Check if you have permissions to write on the destination folder.

Comment: As stated above in my original post, i have checked this and also ran   is_writable($target_path) to check and this came back that is was able to write to the folder, also check CHMOD and have tried 755 and 777

Comment: Where do you define `$photos_uploaded`? Shouldn't it be `$_FILES["photos_uploaded"]` instead?

Comment: To debug something like this, I will usually add a die("HERE") statement in the code and see if I can get it to display.  If I can, I keep moving it downwards in the code until it disappears when I run the code.  It helps narrow down exactly where the issue is stemming from, and allows you to at least start picking apart the right chunk of code.  Do you know if the code preceding the line that moves the file is actually working properly?

Comment: You have to find out what the actual error is. Turn on error displaying, check your logs, there's an error somewhere. Trying to troubleshoot from a 500 response is like <insert clever analogy>, its really hard.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a slash in here:

```
// No slash at the end
$target_path = '../' . $images_dir;
....
// No slash between path and file
$target_path = $target_path . $filename;
                           ^^^^
```

that should be:

```
$target_path = $target_path .'/'. $filename;
```

Comment: You should set ``error_reporting(E_ALL);`` and ``ini_set('display_errors', 'on');`` so you can see where the error occurs.

Comment: And your `is_writeable()` check is too late, you have to put it before the `move_uploaded_file()` in the IF or the `move_uploaded_file()` will just fail before the `is_writable()` check is executed.

Comment: Unfortunately as i do this i get an error 500 page, but it looks to be something to do with the images uploading, as i tested it by stripping all the code out and just getting it to echo hello on upload and it still had a 500 error, when i submit with a no image, it works perfectly.

Comment: What is the size of your image? You should check that it is lower than `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` ini settings. `post_max_size` actually has to be about 30% larger than the file because file uploads are base64-encoded which has about 30% overhead.

Comment: 8mb is post max size and the image is about 326kb.

Comment: Only error from error_reporting on the page is: 
Notice: Undefined variable: photo_category_list in /home/demiblac/public_html/codeblue/classes/plugins/function.portfolioAdminUpload.php on line 46

Comment: Without access to the webserver logs I am out of ideas to debug this.

Comment: But another error: all your file upload inputs are named `photo_filename`, so they override themselves. You should either append a counter or append `[]` to each of the names to create an array.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was the following code, for single image upload - also the main issue that was causing the errors was mod_security trying to write to the root /tmp folder instead of the usr /tmp folder.

```
<?php
/**
 * Smarty plugin
 *
 * @package    Smarty
 * @subpackage PluginsFunction
 */

/**
 * Smarty {portfolioAdminUpload} plugin
 * Type:     function<br>
 * Name:     Display and provide function for image uploading to portfolio<br>
 * Purpose:  fetch file and move to relevant location.
 *
 * @author Kyle Holmes <kholmes at blacknovadesigns dot co dot uk>
 *
 * @param array                    $params   parameters
 * @param Smarty_Internal_Template $template template object
 *
 * @throws SmartyException
 * @return string|null if the assign parameter is passed, Smarty assigns the result to a template variable
 */
function smarty_function_portfolioAdminUpload()
{

global $db;
global $images_dir;

// initialization  
  $photo_upload_fields = '';  
  $counter = 1;  

  // If we want more fields, then use, preupload.php?number_of_fields=20  
  $number_of_fields = (isset($_GET['number_of_fields'])) ?  
    (int)($_GET['number_of_fields']) : 1;


  // Firstly Lets build the Category List  

  try {

                $stmt = $db->query('SELECT category_id,category_name FROM mod_portfolio_category') ;
                while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
                $photo_category_list .= '<option value="'.$row['category_id'].'">'.$row['category_name'].'</option>';
        }

  // Lets build the Image Uploading fields                      
                 while($counter <= $number_of_fields) { 
                        $photo_upload_fields .= '<tr><td>  
                              Photo'.$counter.'  
                              <input name="photo_filename"  
                            type="file" />  
                            </td></tr>  
                            <tr><td>  
                              Caption:  
                              <textarea name="photo_caption" cols="30"  
                                rows="1"></textarea>  
                            </td></tr>';
                                $counter++;  
                } 

            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }

  // Final Output  
  echo '<html>   

<form enctype="multipart/form-data"  
  action="" method="post"  
  name="upload_form"> 
<div class="title">Lets upload Photos</div>    
  <table width="90%" border="0"  
    align="center" style="width: 90%;">  
    <tr><td>  
      Select Category  
      <select name="category">  
      '.$photo_category_list.'  
      </select>  
    </td></tr>  
    <! - Insert the image fields here --> ' 
    .$photo_upload_fields.' 
    <tr><td>  
      <input type="submit" name="submit"  
        value="Add Photos" />  
    </td></tr>  
  </table>  
</form>  
</body>  
</html>';  

//if form has been submitted process it
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

// Fetch the image caption array 
    $photo_captions = $_POST['photo_caption'];

    $photo_category = $_POST['category'];

// Is the image really an image?
    $validextensions =  array(    
      'image/pjpeg' => 'jpg',   
      'image/jpeg' => 'jpg',   
      'image/gif' => 'gif',   
      'image/bmp' => 'bmp',   
      'image/x-png' => 'png',
      'image/png' => 'png'  
    ); 

// Get File Type
    $file = $_FILES['photo_filename']['tmp_name'];
    $filetype = $_FILES['photo_filename']['type'];
    $file_extension = $validextensions[$filetype];          


// Set Target Path for file upload 
    $target_path = '../' . $images_dir;


// New Id generated             
    $new_id = $db->lastInsertId();      

// Generate a new name
    $simpleName = $_FILES["photo_filename"]['name'];   
    $filename = $new_id.rand().$_FILES["photo_filename"]['name'];

        try {

                //insert into database
                $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT mod_portfolio_photos SET photo_filename = :photoFilename, photo_caption = :photoCaption, photo_category = :photoCategory') ;
                $stmt->execute(array(
                    ':photoFilename' => $filename,
                    ':photoCaption' => $photo_captions,
                    ':photoCategory' => $photo_category,
                ));

            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }

    if (in_array($file_extension, $validextensions) && is_writable($target_path)) {

// Set the target path with a new name of image.        
    $target_path = $target_path . $filename;     

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo_filename"]['tmp_name'], $target_path) ) {
// If file moved to uploads folder.
    echo '<span id="noerror">'.$simpleName.' uploaded successfully!.</span><br/><br/>';
    } 
    else {     
//  If File Was Not Moved.
    echo '<span id="error">'.$simpleName.' Failed to Upload - please try again!.</span><br/><br/>';
    }}
    else {
//   If File Size And File Type Was Incorrect.
    echo '<span id="error">***Invalid file Size or Type***</span><br/><br/>';
    }

    $size = GetImageSize($target_path);    

// Wide Image    
    if($size[0] > $size[1])    
    {     
     $thumbnail_width = 100;     
     $thumbnail_height = (int)(100 * $size[1] / $size[0]);     
    }     

// Tall Image    
    else    
    {    
      $thumbnail_width = (int)(100 * $size[0] / $size[1]);    
      $thumbnail_height = 100;    
    }

    $gd_function_suffix = array(      
      'image/pjpeg' => 'JPEG',     
      'image/jpeg' => 'JPEG',     
      'image/gif' => 'GIF',     
      'image/bmp' => 'WBMP',     
      'image/x-png' => 'PNG'     
    );

// Get the Name Suffix on basis of the mime type     
    $function_suffix = $gd_function_suffix[$filetype];     

// Build Function name for ImageCreateFromSUFFIX     
    $function_to_read = 'ImageCreateFrom' . $function_suffix;     

// Build Function name for ImageSUFFIX     
    $function_to_write = 'Image' . $function_suffix;

// Read the source file     
    $source_handle = $function_to_read($target_path);     

    if ($source_handle) {     
// Let's create a blank image for the thumbnail     
      $destination_handle =     
        ImageCreateTrueColor($thumbnail_width, $thumbnail_height);     

// Now we resize it     
      ImageCopyResampled($destination_handle, $source_handle,     
        0, 0, 0, 0, $thumbnail_width, $thumbnail_height, $size[0], $size[1]);     
    }     

// Let's save the thumbnail     
    $function_to_write($destination_handle, '../' . $images_dir . 'thumbnails/' . $filename);

    }
    }
```